# Powershell -NoNewWindow not working as expected

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-1.0

Basically I want to switch user in powershell in the same window (dont want to open a new one).

```
$username = "xxxxx"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Objet System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username,$password
Start-Process powershell.exe -NoNewWindow -Credential $creds
```

But instead of launching powershell in same window it launches it in a new window which doesnt even work I cant type anything into its just a blinking cursor.

Comment: You can't run a process within a process in a different context like that.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 than is there any other way to switch  user in powershell?

Comment: Within the same conhost?  None that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, try to describe what you need to do in detail since the approach you're using might be misguided. Are you just trying to run commands as a different user within a script? If so, use the methods described here : https://www.itdroplets.com/run-a-command-as-a-different-user-in-powershell/

I particularly like the start-job method which I use sometimes, example:

```
#Shows who is the current user
whoami
""

$username = "DOMAIN\USER"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username,$password


$GetProcessJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
#Shows who is the current user, in this case it's the user you provided credentials for. Everything in this scriptblock will run in his context.

whoami


} -Credential $Credential

#Wait until the job is completed
Wait-Job $GetProcessJob | Out-Null

#Get the Job results
$GetProcessResult = Receive-Job -Job $GetProcessJob

#Print the Job results
$GetProcessResult
```

If you truly just want to just launch another powershell.exe process as another user,
the only way I know of would be to simply start the new process and exit the first one after that command, this way you have only the new window running as the user provided.

```
$username = "DOMAIN\USER"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username,$password
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $creds ;Exit
```